# How do I tack a string onto a variable and evaluated the entire thing as a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables, dynamic

I have the following Ruby code:

```
module BigTime
  FOO1_MONEY_PIT = 500
  FOO2_MONEY_PIT = 501
  
  class LoseMoney
    @@SiteName = 'FOO1'
    @site_num = @@SiteName_MONEY_PIT
    def other_unimportant_stuff
      whatever
    end
  end
end
```

So, what I'm trying to do here is set the SiteName and then use SiteName and combine it with the string _MONEY_PIT so I can access FOO1_MONEY_PIT and store its contents (500 in this case) in @site_num.  Of course, the above code doesn't work, but there must be a way I can do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: It can be done, but it's kludgey and would require some metaprogramming. You're better off using a Hash.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically get the value of a constant, you can use [`Module#const_get`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

```ruby
module BigTime
  FOO1_MONEY_PIT = 500
  FOO2_MONEY_PIT = 501
  
  class LoseMoney
    @@SiteName = 'FOO1'
    @site_num = BigTime.const_get(:"#{@@SiteName}_MONEY_PIT")
  end
end
```

Do *not*, under any circumstance, use [`Kernel#eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) for this. `Kernel#eval` is extremely dangerous in any context where there is even the *slightest* possibility that an attacker may be able to control parts of the argument.

For example, if a user can choose the name of the site, and they name their site `require 'fileutils'; FileUtils.rm_rf('/')`, then Ruby will *happily* evaluate that code, just like you told it to!

`Kernel#eval` is very dangerous and you should *not* get into the habit of just throwing an `eval` at a problem. It is a very specialized tool that should only be employed when there is no other option (spoiler alert: there almost always is another option), and only after a thorough security review.

Please note that dynamically constructing variable names is already a code smell by itself, regardless of whether you use `eval` or not. It pretty much always points to a design flaw somewhere. In general, you can almost guaranteed replace the multiple variables with a data structure. E.g. in this case something like this:

```ruby
module BigTime
  MONEY_PITS = {
    'FOO1' => 500,
    'FOO2' => 501,
  }.freeze
  
  class LoseMoney
    @@SiteName = 'FOO1'
    @site_num = MONEY_PITS[@@SiteName]
  end
end
```

Comment: In your second example, *@site_num* isn't accessible outside of class definition time. `BigTime::LoseMoney.new.instance_variable_get :@site_num #=> nil`

Comment: Yes, that's how the OP designed it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I've tried it as you proposed in your last example and it doesn't seem to work.  But, let me provide a little bit more information.  I've actually got an array I'm trying to access to that may be complicating this.  Example:

`
module BigTime
  SITE1 = 20
  MONEY_PITS[SITE1][:site_num] = 500

  SITE2 = 40
  MONEY_PITS[SITE1][:site_num] = 501
  
class LoseMoney
    @@SiteName = 'SITE1'
    @site_num = MONEY_PITS[@@SiteName][:site_num]
  end
end
`

@site_num should be set to 500, but @@SiteName doesn't seem to be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out how to make the comments format well...

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor this as to use a Hash for your name lookups, and a getter method to retrieve it for easy testing/validation. For example:

```
module BigTime
  MONEY_PITS       = { FOO1: 500, FOO2: 501 }
  MONEY_PIT_SUFFIX = '_MONEY_PIT'
  
  class LoseMoney
    @@site = :FOO1

    def initialize
      site_name
    end

    def site_name
      @site_name ||= '%d%s' % [MONEY_PITS[@@site], MONEY_PIT_SUFFIX]
    end
  end
end

BigTime::LoseMoney.new.site_name
#=> "500_MONEY_PIT"
```